# Error 401 trying to request an image from zoho creator api

Tags: reactjs, api, express, zoho

Hi guys I'm building a small app using react and api from Zoho creator, I made a backend using express where I get a json object,but when I try to access to an image from my frontend I get an error 401.
Here my express code.

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors")
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
var whitelist = ['https://zine-hosteleria-frontend12012023.onrender.com']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const urlPost = ("https://accounts.zoho.eu/oauth/v2/token?refresh_token=1000.3dbdad6937dc0800c4dcc662cd14d173.86efb18e337989bebb3ff4c05582c94c&client_id=1000.NQL17JHK3Y62Y178TO0E3FQC6MBQJV&client_secret=5d04ad135862e7313377484af55efa1f41c1f49a39&grant_type=refresh_token")
const urlGet = "https://creator.zoho.eu/api/v2/hostienda1/Product-Catalog/report/Product_Details";
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.get
const peticion = fetch(urlPost,{
      method: 'POST',
      redirect: 'follow'
    });
    peticion
    .then((ans)=>{return ans.json()})
    .then((resp)=>{
      const reslt = resp.access_token;
      return app.get("*", async (req,res)=>{
        const response = await fetch(urlGet,{
        method: "GET",
        headers:{
            'Authorization':`Zoho-oauthtoken ${reslt}`,
          }})
          const result = await response.json()
          const test = result.data
          test.map(function(product){
                if (true){
            product.Product_Images[0]=
            "https://creator.zoho.eu"+product.Product_Images[0].display_value -> here I have to add https://creator... because my json object doesn't fetch that route

                return product.Product_Images
                }
              })
         
          res.json(test)
```

[Here an example of my json object from zoho, I want to access to the image field but I can't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrQr0.png)
I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me.

I wish to render all those images from Zoho API in my react app.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an HTTP status code of 401 back from Zoho, which means that the request is [unauthenticated/the authorization failed](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/v2/status-codes.html)

The official description from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) is:

> 401 Unauthorized The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 401
> Unauthorized response status code indicates that the client request
> has not been completed because it lacks valid authentication
> credentials for the requested resource.

This means that your request is failing because of invalid credentials. To me it appears that you are trying to use zoho connect API authorization for [creator](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/v2/generate-token.html) which appears to have a different API authentication schema